# CSSの@font-faceで指定したWebフォントがダウンロードされないようにしたい

Tags: html, css, font

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
  src: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf");
}
```

たとえば、CSSでWebフォントを指定するとき、普通はこのように `@font-face` で指定すると思います。
しかし、開発者ツール等でCSSファイルを開いてしまえば、Webフォントのリンクが分かるため、第三者にダウンロードされる可能性があります。フリーフォントなら問題ありませんが、有料フォントともなるとダウンロードされないように対応する必要があります。

そこで、どのようにすれば、Webフォントがダウンロードされないようにすることができるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webフォントとして利用可能なフォントの場合、PV数に応じた料金が設定されていることが多いようなので、ライセンス規約に応じて利用している分には心配する必要がありません。
もし、Web利用のライセンスが設定されていないフォントの場合、Webフォントとして利用してはいけない可能性があるのでご確認いただいた方がよいです。

Answer (score 1):

そもそも**リソースファイルはブラウザで表示されている時点でローカルにダウンロードされている**状態です。

ダウンロードを防ぎたいなら質問文の第三者に該当する人はそのフォントを表示できないようにするしかありません。
フォントファイルにIP制限やBASIC認証等のアクセス制限をかけてダウンロード(表示)を許可するユーザーと分けてみてはどうでしょうか？